# python Django 403 forbidden when changing email

Tags: python, django, csrf

I'd like to change user email using standard Django methods, but before the email will be changed, password from form and from DB must match. And I;m getting 403 error `CSRF token missing or incorrect.` This is my `form`:

```
class ChangeMailForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(label = (u'Podaj hasło'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    email = forms.EmailField(label = (u'Podaj nowy adres email'))

    def clean_email(self):
        mail = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Taki email jest w bazie")
        return mail
```

my `view`:

```
def ChangeEmail(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangeMailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            usr = request.user
            u = User.objects.filter(username=usr)
            if not User.objects.filter(username=usr).check_password(form.cleaned_data['password']):
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            mail = form.cleaned_data['email']
            u.new_email(mail)
            u.save()
        else:
            return render_to_response('changeemail.html', {'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = ChangeMailForm()
        return render_to_response('changeemail.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and part of my `template`:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.errors %}<p id="correct">Popraw następujące pola:</p>{% endif %}
    <table id="change">
        <tr>
            <td {% if form.password.errors %} class="error" {% endif %}>Podaj hasło:</td>
            <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td {% if form.email.errors %} class="error" {% endif %}>Podaj nowy adres:</td>
            <td>{{ form.email }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="sub">
    <input type="submit"  value="Wykonaj" alt="login" id="submit" />
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: added traceback after putting @csrf_exempt decorator**

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/changeemail/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'dailyresults',
 'trainingresults',
 'athlete',
 'easy_pdf')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "D:\Programy\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Programy\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Inz\trening\athlete\views.py" in ChangeEmail
  93.             if not User    .objects.filter(username=usr).check_password(form.cleaned_data['password']):
```

Exception Type: AttributeError at /changeemail/
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'check_password'

Comment: What is happening with the current code? A quick assumption - you'll probably wan't to change the line in your clean_email method to `if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()`

Comment: @IanPrice, I've added reason why I'm posting (2nd line), and I cant change the line you've suggested - if email is in DB, it will return ValidationError "This email is in DB"

Comment: @AdamP, this line is wrong: `User.objects.filter(username=usr).check_password(...)`, `u` is a queryset which itself doesn't have `check_password` method. You need to change to something like `queryset().first()`, or `u[0]` to access the `User` object (of course you need to verify if that exists, otherwise it will be `[]`).

Comment: Although what I mentioned above is true, `CSRF` is missing hints the error from somewhere else in your code, not passing/verifying it correctly.

Comment: @AdamP, could you try putting a `@csrf_exempt` decorator in your view just to check if other parts work? And please post your full stack trace

Comment: @Anzel, I've added traceback with `@csrf_exempt`

Comment: @AdamP, try fixing that error with my suggestion above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line from:

```
u = User.objects.filter(username=usr)
if not User.objects.filter(username=usr).check_password(...):
```

to this:

```
u = User.objects.filter(username=usr).first()
if u and u.check_password(...):
    ...
```

Why it will throw an error in first approach is because `u` is a queryset in a **list** which itself doesn't have `check_password` method. But you can access *User Object* using `queryset().first()` or slicing it `u[0]` and get the *User object* (of course you need to verify if that exists, otherwise it will be []).

And please ensure that `csrf_token` indeed exist in your request, you can use **logging** and check like:

```
import logging
...
#your view
logging.info('request MEAT for csrf: %s', request.META.get('CSRF_COOKIE'))
```

And see if it exists.

Also you may try clearing your browser cache, or test with another browser (new session, or private session) and see if error still occurs.

#### updated

When you need to update the **email** field, just use a normal model **save** method:

```
# above code... and being verified ...
u.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
u.save()
```

That's it.

Comment: Ok, but could please tell me how do I actually update the `email` field? I've tried with `u.update(email=request.POST['email'])` and `u.update(email=mail)` but it returns me that User has no `update` attribute. with `u.email(mail)` I get `unicode not callable`. I've put logging in to my view, but I don't see any infos from it.

Comment: @AdamP, well it's just normal django model save() method?? OK, i'll update the answer for you

Comment: Wow, it was easier than I thought. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AdamP, not a problem ;) Yes it's actually quite easy to modify/update the model than we used to think.